# pine script strategy.close is not working

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i try to quote an reverse order when the price is crossover/under a priceline, but seems not working. in the list of trade. the"entry short, is trigger by "entry short1", which is correct. but the exit surpassingly is trigger by stoploss or strategy.close. the entry of the long, is get close by the entry of short.

```
    //@variable Stop-loss price for exit commands.
var float stopLoss   = na
//@variable Take-profit price for exit commands.
var float takeProfit = na


// Trading logic
if isLong and barstate.isconfirmed
    if strategy.position_size <0
        stopLoss   := close * 0.99
        takeProfit := close * 1.01
    strategy.exit("exit1","short1", stop=stopLoss,limit = takeProfit)
    strategy.exit("exit2","short2", stop=stopLoss,limit = takeProfit)
    strategy.entry("long1", strategy.long, comment="entry long1")
    strategy.cancel("short1")
    strategy.cancel("short2")
    

if isLong and islong2 and strategy.position_size >0
    strategy.entry("long2", strategy.long, comment="entry long2")

if isShort and strategy.position_size > 0
    if strategy.position_size == 0.0
        stopLoss   := close * 0.99
        takeProfit := close * 1.01
    strategy.exit("exit1","long1", stop=stopLoss,limit = takeProfit)
    strategy.exit("exit2","long2", stop=stopLoss,limit = takeProfit)
    strategy.entry("short1", strategy.short, comment="entry short1")
    strategy.cancel("long1")
    strategy.cancel("long2")  

if isShort and isshort2 and strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.entry("short2", strategy.short, comment="entry short2")
```